# Does the following operator have a unique fixed function? Do iterations of the operator converge?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

The functions considered are positive real for positive real $x$, and monotonically increasing to infinity. Given such a function $f(x)$, define the (nonlinear) operator $f\mapsto f^*$ by
$$
f^*(x) := 1 + \frac {x}{f(1)} 
+ \frac{x^2}{ f(1)f(2)}
 + \frac{x^3}{ f(1)f(2)f(3)} +\dots
= 1 + \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}
 \frac{x^n}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^n f(k)}.
$$
The new function $f^*$ is again positive real for positive real $x$ and monotonically increasing to infinity. (In fact $f^*$ is an entire function, not that we need that.) So this process can be iterated. It seems that, no matter what function we start with, the result converges pointwise.

Comment: soooo, the question is what, exactly? contained in the title?

Comment: Yes. it seems the title is enough, no?